# OP amp output can't go below below 1.8V

Tags: operational-amplifier, ph

I'm kind a new in electronics so pardon me if i ask a stupid question.

I'm trying to follow this schematic but i'm using op07 as buffer and LM336 as voltage reference. What happens is that the op-amp (U1) output cannot go below 1.8 volt but it was OK above that.

[image]

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on what Andy mentioned, when using an opamp in a single supply configuration you need to create a virtual ground which is usually Vcc/2. This is what R1 and R2 are doing in the circuit you've attached, although what this means is that you're never going to be able to get 0V on the output, you will always have an offset of Vcc/2.
In the circuit they're using 1.024V as a reference voltage. This means that the virtual ground is going to be at Vcc/2 which is 0.512V (If you look at the circuit you can see they've even mentioned Voffset = 512mV)

Now you mentioned you're using an LM336, this is a 2.5V voltage reference. In the same single supply configuration you're never going to be able to get below Vcc/2 which in your case will be 1.25V. Changing your reference voltage to an [LM4140A-1](http://uk.farnell.com/texas-instruments/lm4140acm-1-0/voltage-ref-series-1-024v-soic/dp/1286879) or similar voltage reference should solve your problem

Comment: I think you've turned my simple answer into something baffling LOL.

Comment: The offset voltage is due to the offset created by the virtual ground on the non-inverting input of the op-amp, saying it's because of the supply voltage isn't necessarily true as even if he switched to using the LMP7221 as in the circuit diagram and used a 5V supply he still wouldn't see the 512mV offset he'd expect due to using a 2.5V reference for the virtual ground rather than 1V as shown in the circuit

Comment: Doesn't make a difference what offset he's using, he still won't able to get closer to the rail

Comment: It does make a difference, Andy's answer is correct but if the OP does just change the op amp he's still going to have a higher offset than what the schematic he's following does. Hence why my answer starts with "To expand on what Andy mentioned"

Comment: thank you very much for you comment, i am aware that i wont get 512mv due to different reference voltage..i was changing the R2 with 10K pot hoping i will be able to set the output to the offset level that i want.

Answer (score 5):

Read the data sheet on page 3. With a +/- 15V supply the output is typically restricted to the range +/-13V. So, with ground as your negative power rail don't expect to get as low as 2V on the output.

Comment: As well as Andy's comment, note that the OP-07 is utterly unsuited for a high impedance pH sensor. The bias current is as much as 6nA, which will **completely** swamp your signal. You have to actually read and understand the data sheets and designs before substituting special parts willy-nilly.

Comment: thank you very much for you comment, i was thought that 6nA bias current is small enough to not make signal swap..do you have  advice on which Op-Amp should i use to replace this LM7721?? i had a hard time find it in my place..